# in Primefaces datatable can I use "filter by" with two fields?

Tags: primefaces

I want to use something like this:

```
filterBy="#{proyecto.clientes.id_cliente}, #{proyecto.clientes.descripcion}"
```

Is there a way to filter a column by two different fields in the same filterbox?

I have searched in documentation and in this web without finding nothing.

EDIT: Of course, both fields are rendered in the same column as this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{proyecto.clientes.id_cliente}   -   #{proyecto.clientes.descripcion}" />
```

Comment: Create one String variable on your bean side(Or server side) and merge both the required Strings values in that variable. Now access newly created variable from view side and check for filtering.

Comment: That'll work. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to hear it! I've moved my comments into an answer so you can accept it as the valid answer and mark the question as 'solved'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one String variable on your Bean side(Or server side) and merge both the required Strings values in that variable.

Now you can access newly created variable at your view side and check for filtering.